# Can a dog contract a sexually transmitted infection?

Tags: dogs, breeding, infections

My friend has a dog that has mated with so many female dogs. I've been a little worried about this dog lately because he is becoming more promiscuous.

Are there dog sexually transmitted infections (STIs)? How prone is this dog to contract them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**, dogs have risk of STD's or STI's. [Canine herpesvirus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canine_herpesvirus) and  [Canine transmissible venereal tumor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canine_transmissible_venereal_tumor) are among the diseases which can be sexually transferable among dogs. So you should always have to take care of it.

(Source:[vetinfo.com](http://www.vetinfo.com/sexually-transmitted-disease-dogs.html))